# Velocity "fadeIn" Issue with Version 2.0.0+ (including 2.0.5)

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I am a new programmer of JS. I'm trying to learn some HTML animations on JS and I found an amazing package called "VelocityJS". But when I use the

```
$ele.velocity("fadeIn")
```

My chrome keeps throwing an error:

```
VelocityJS: First argument (fadeIn) was not a property map, a known action, or a registered redirect. Aborting.
```

Now in the [official website](http://velocityjs.org/),
Chapter "Command" - "fadeIn and fadeOut", there are 2 examples including the usage. But as far as I tested, It only works for the version under 1.5.0.
I wish I can be told if there's any substitution for this after version 2.0.0 (also called Velocity V2)?

And In Chapter "Basics: Performance", it's told that **Never** use jQuery's $.animate() and $.fade() functions. They **slow everything else down**, including other animation libraries.

**JS FILE**

```
try {
$(test).velocity("fadeIn", { duration: 1500 }).velocity("fadeOut", { delay: 500, duration: 1500 });
} catch {}
```

**HTML FILE**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.js"></script>
<div id='test' style="background-color:black">
    some place holder
</div>
```

copy and past the file above to the [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEgZjv) at codepen.io

THIS GIVES THE RIGHT OUTPUT.
but the Velocity version of this page is 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js
As I want to change the "marginTop" property, I need to use a later version.
But I cannot find any documentation on the latest version.

With version 1.5.0, neither of the "marginTop" or "margin-top" works.
With version 2.0.0 - 2.0.5, 
    $(elementID).velocity("fadeIn",{duration:1000}) 
has no effect.
Fixing either one is fine for me so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity V2 is in beta yet. You could always use direct CSS attributes manipulation with:

```
element.velocity({
    p: { opacity: 1 },
    o: { duration: 1500 }
}).velocity({
    p: { opacity: 0 },
    o: { delay: 500, duration: 1500 }
});
```

The documentation on for V2 is not maintained on the main site yet. You should instead refer for the docs in the [Github wiki](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/wiki)